# Get category name from category id through relationship. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have looked through the forum, but the solutions I have seen so far, aren't aligning with the issues I'm getting, so, I was hoping someone more informed would help out.

So I have a Category modem and A post model and there relationship is as follows;

on post model:

```
public function postcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo(PostCategory::class);
}
```

on category model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('approved', 'true');
}
```

and I am using slugs to retrieve all the posts that belongs to a certain category slug, using this function:

```
public function cats($category){
    $posts = PostCategory::where('category_slug', $category)->first()->posts;
    $category = PostCategory::where('category_slug', $category)->first();
    return view('posts', compact('posts', 'category')); 
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the name of the category with the category id stored in the posts table. for example, if I have a category id of 1 and on the category table, if the id number 1 is PHP, how do I return the name PHP instead of the id 1?

Secondly, if I wanted to paginate the view where posts is being compacted to, how do I do that? I switched the code in the controller to this:

```
$posts = PostCategory::with('posts')->where('category_slug', $category)->paginate(15);
```

when I dd that line of code, it returns some values (with relations), but when I pass that to the view, I get errors.

Hopefully, someone see this and help me out. :D

Comment: `"when I pass that to the view, I get errors."`. What is the error?

Comment: And if the view fails, please include the view

Comment: Hi cyberkid, you need to give some more info on what error is being shown in the view.  Also you probably want to remove the where('approved', true) from the posts function, then add it as a scope method.  If you really want a method like this on the model then call it approvedPosts, as at present you limit yourself from retrieving unapproved posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Category Model :

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

On Controller :

```
public function cats($slug)
{
    $category = PostCategory::whereSlug($slug)->firstorFail();
    $posts= $category->posts()->where('approved', 'true')->paginate(15);
    return view('category.show', compact('posts', 'category'));
}
```

On View :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
 $post->title
 ....
@endforeach
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

Comment: Hi xNoJustice, The OP's implementation of the posts function is cleaner than your getPosts function.  He could then use a scope to pull in the approved posts.  Also there is no need to use a WhereId function as find is cleaner and does the same thing.  But that is not required anyway if good relationship management is used.

Comment: If I got it right, I fixed it. Would you look again? @ColinMD

Comment: You now have the relationship but you shouldn't put additional queries on the relationship method, what happens if the OP wanted all none approved posts, or would like to paginate 30 results or not order it, because that logic is coded on the relationship function you cant do it.  So everything after the hasMany should be removed, first to a scope method like scopeApproved()  then orderBy and paginate can be added in the controller as and when required.

Comment: You're right. But he want that before that the question. That is not first question. If you look at her old questions, you can understand why I did so.

Comment: As per my comment to the OP, to do this you want to call it approvedPosts and not posts.  If you look at the question from yesterday, the correct answer said to call it approvedPosts.  The relationship for 'posts' should just return the relationship to the Post' model and any further queries should be scoped or added after the relationship method.  With regards to orderBy and pagination, in my opinion its always better to do this in the controller, lets say the user needs to implement an api call and return 300 posts per call, it cant be done in the implementation given..

Comment: If I do this, then how do I get the name of the category?
I can get the id from $post->category_id, but how do I get that category name instead of the id? I have tried doing this $post->postcategory->category_name, but it doesn't work. I get this error: Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object

Comment: okay, so how do I return the category name? I have copied in your edits into my controller, but on my view, I'm still getting the error: Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object, if I try to get the category name from relation: $post->postcategory->category_name, on my view.

Comment: `$category->category_name` ?

Comment: I was so desperate, I wasn't even paying attention to my code. I feel embarrassed that I couldn't figure that last line out. Thanks Bud!
If you're good at Laravel and if you have a YT channel, can you make a video on how to include reviews/rating to posts?

Comment: very simple where your show function, add this `$post->increment('reviews', 1)` If i increase my upload speed i'll think that xd